# Cannot allocate free space back to main disk

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, bootcamp, spaces

I've uninstalled Windows 10 from my Mac via Boot Camp and the space that I allocated to it has turned into free space. I can't seem to remove it and add it back to my total disk storage.

When using Disk Utility, I get this error;

[image]

Here's the diskutil list;

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         27.7 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         555.0 GB   disk1s2
   3:                        EFI NO NAME                 104.9 MB   disk1s5
                    (free space)                         444.9 GB   -

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +582.7 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume MacOS                   8.8 GB     disk2s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 8.8 GB     disk2s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     244.2 GB   disk2s2
   4:                APFS Volume Preboot                 2.2 GB     disk2s3
   5:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.1 GB     disk2s4
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      3.2 GB     disk2s5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra hidden EFI partition which is preventing you from regaining the free space.

The commands to regain the free space are given below. Before entering the commands, check to see if the output from `diskutil list` is the same as you posted. I state this because if you have restarted your Mac, then most likely `disk1s5` will change to `disk1s3`.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk1s5
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I would have never guess a hidden EFI could be the cause of this issue. I wish I could upvote your answer to show my gratitude.